# Modify column values based on group dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8),
                 var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'h'),
                 var2 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
                 var3 = c(21, 50, 40, 30, 29, 45, 33, 51, 70, 46))
```

I want to modify var3 when ID=3, var1=c and var2 is 0, so that the value increases by +5

Input:

```
   ID var1 var2 var3
1   1    a    1   21
2   2    b    1   50
3   3    c    1   40
4   3    c    0   30
5   4    d    1   29
6   5    e    1   45
7   5    f    0   33
8   7    g    0   51
9   7    h    1   70
10  8    h    0   46
```

Desired output:

```
   ID var1 var2 var3
1   1    a    1   21
2   2    b    1   50
3   3    c    1   40
4   3    c    0   35
5   4    d    1   29
6   5    e    1   45
7   5    f    0   33
8   7    g    0   51
9   7    h    1   70
10  8    h    0   46
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `case_when` to set multiple conditions and add 5 to the column or keep the same value like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(var3 = case_when(ID == 3 & var1 == "c" & var2 == 0 ~ var3 + 5,
                          TRUE ~ var3))
#>    ID var1 var2 var3
#> 1   1    a    1   21
#> 2   2    b    1   50
#> 3   3    c    1   40
#> 4   3    c    0   35
#> 5   4    d    1   29
#> 6   5    e    1   45
#> 7   5    f    0   33
#> 8   7    g    0   51
#> 9   7    h    1   70
#> 10  8    h    0   46
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we create a logical expression and update

```
i1 <- with(df, ID ==3  & var1 == "c" & var2 == 0 )
df$var3[i1] <- df$var3[i1] + 5
```

-output

```
> df
   ID var1 var2 var3
1   1    a    1   21
2   2    b    1   50
3   3    c    1   40
4   3    c    0   35
5   4    d    1   29
6   5    e    1   45
7   5    f    0   33
8   7    g    0   51
9   7    h    1   70
10  8    h    0   46
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using `data.table` and `ifelse`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, var3 := ifelse(ID == 3 & var1=="c" & var2 == 0, var3 + 5, var3), ]

df
    ID var1 var2 var3
 1:  1    a    1   21
 2:  2    b    1   50
 3:  3    c    1   40
 4:  3    c    0   35
 5:  4    d    1   29
 6:  5    e    1   45
 7:  5    f    0   33
 8:  7    g    0   51
 9:  7    h    1   70
10:  8    h    0   46
```